# Draw plot only inside a circle with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, interpolation, draw

I have scattered data and I am interpolating it to gridded data. Afterwards I draw everything with the contourf function. In the end I just want to draw everything inside a defined circle. Everything else should be white, but I don"t know how to achieve this. Is there a simple way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


def func(x, y):
  return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]

points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])


grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')

plt.contourf(grid_x,grid_y,grid_z0)

plt.savefig("plot_data_in_circle.png")
```

Edit: I attach the plot which comes out from my code:
[image: picture produced by the current code]

And this is how it should look like:

[image: .]

Comment: Can you post a (MS paint) picture of what you roughly want it to look like? :)

Comment: Options you have: (a) Setting undesired values to nan, (b) mask the array, (c) use a clip path. There should be examples for that around. If not, it would be helpful to know at which point the matplotlib documentation can be improved.

Comment: I added a picture how it should look like ;)

Comment: Did you try any of the above options? At which point do they fail?

Comment: I tried  <br/> <pre>ax = plt.axes()

patch = patches.Circle((0, 0), radius=0.8, transform=ax.transData)
ax.set_clip_path(patch)<code>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by creating a [`Circle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html) patch, and then setting that as the `clip_path`.

To use a `clip_path`, one would usually store the artist on which you want to apply the clipping, and then use `.set_clip_path` on that. In this case, since you are using [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf), there is no method `.set_clip_path`, so we have to iterate over the [`PathCollections`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection) stored with the [`QuadContourSet`](https://matplotlib.org/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet) returned from `contourf`, and set the clip path on each of them using the [`set_clip_path` method](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.set_clip_path).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.patches as patches

def func(x, y):
  return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]

points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])


grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cs = ax.contourf(grid_x,grid_y,grid_z0)

circ = patches.Circle((0.6, 0.4), 0.3, transform=ax.transData)
for coll in cs.collections:
    coll.set_clip_path(circ)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea how to scale it to a circle? And I tried to include a colorbar. But this isn't working anymore

Comment: do you mean why is it an ellipse rather than a circle? That's because the aspect ratio of the axes is not equal. Try `ax.set_aspect('equal')` and you should see a circle.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!! This is a very nice answer ;)